# g++/c++ makefile dependency generation to ignore boost headers?

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I am using the makefile dependency generation options in g++ (and c++) like this:

```
c++ -I/opt/local/include -MM main.cc
```

On a file, main.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

#include "projects/all_projects.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  // ...
}
```

The -MM option prevents the generation of dependencies for iostream which is good, but not for shared_ptr.hpp.  Is there a way I can prevent the dependency generation for boost headers (or even for any headers in angle brackets for that matter)?

I read that earlier versions of gcc used to consider any headers in angle brackets as system headers, but that is no longer the case.

Comment: Having an incomplete dependency tree is a recipe for inconsistent builds. System header files do update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `c++ -isystem /opt/local/include -MM main.cc`

(and `man gcc` :-) )